# jQueryで画像のsrc情報が取得できません。

Tags: javascript, jquery

画像がクリックされたときに、クリックされた「src情報」を取得したいのですが、うまくいきません。(undefinedと出ます。)どなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

---

【script】

```
//対象の画像がクリックされたときの処理

    $(document).on('click','.sel_page', function(event){
         var imgSrc = $('.sel_page').attr('src');
    });
```

【HTML】

```
<div class="sel_page">
            <img src="img/test1.png" id="color0000"/>        
            <img src="img/test2.png" id="color0001"/>        
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.sel_page')` はimgではなくそれを囲ってるdivですよね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.sel_page')` は、imgを囲うdivなので、srcを取ろうとしても取れません。
イベントが起こった要素は[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Event/target)で取れるので
例えば、以下の様にします。

```
$(document).on('click','.sel_page', function(event){
     var imgSrc = event.target.src;
     //alert(imgSrc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.sel_page').on('click','.img', function(event){
   const imgSrc = this.src; 
   // ...
});
```